# Creating and connecting a socket indipendently from the IP version using sockaddr_storage

Tags: c, sockets, unix, network-programming

I'm writing a client that can connect both to an IPv4 and an IPv6 address, making the code as generale as possible.
I used the `getaddrinfo`function to which I pass the string of the IP address, and from that I obtain the address family (at this point I know if it's IPv4 or IPv6). Now I need to bind that address and the port to a sockaddr structure. I've read that in order to make it general I should use sockaddr_storage and then using it by casting it to sockaddr, but I don't understand how to fill sockaddr_storage with the address and the port needed for the connection.

Thanks for your attention.

NB. I want it to work on UNIX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/sys/socket.h.html) only says that the `sockaddr_storage` should be

> - Large enough to accommodate all supported protocol-specific address structures
> - Aligned at an appropriate boundary so that pointers to it can be cast as pointers to protocol-specific address structures and used to access the fields of those structures without alignment problems

And

> The sockaddr_storage structure shall contain at least the following members:
>
> `sa_family_t   ss_family`

There's some notes saying that the `family` structure member for all `sockaddr`-family structures will be at the same place, but that's about it.

So the I would say that the "best" way to use it is to have special cases for IPv4 and IPv6 that fills in the correct `sockaddr_in` or `sockaddr_in6` structures, then `memcpy` them into a `sockaddr_storage` structure that can later be used.